# How to refresh template of component by changing variable in other component Angular 13

Tags: angular

I have component HeaderComponent with the following template :

```
<button *ngIf="isConnected">Logout</button>
```

And the template in composant LoginComponent

```
<button (click)="login()">login</button>
```

In AppComponent :

```
<app-header></app-header>
<app-login></app-login>
```

I would like to show Logout button when I click login button

Thank you for your helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome Paul.

This is a good use case for a service. Generate a service with `ng g service <path>/<serviceName>`. Inside, we can put a `subject` that the `HeaderComponent` can `subscribe` to, and the `LoginComponent` can pass values to.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class LoginStateService {
  subject = new Subject<boolean>();
}
```

You may actually want to bundle all of your login functions in this service, but I'll just describe setting the state for simplicity.

To subscribe in the `HeaderComponent`

```js
loginSub = new Subscription();
isLoggedIn = false;

constructor(private loginState: LoginStateService) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.loginSub = this.loginState.subject.subscribe(
    (value) => (this.isLoggedIn = value)
  );
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.loginSub.unsubscribe();
}
```

Unsubscribing is probably not necessary here, but it's good practice to prevent memory leaks.

To pass a value from `Login Component`

```js
constructor(private loginState: LoginStateService) {}

login() {
  //Do some login stuff
  this.loginState.subject.next(true);
}

logout() {
  //Do some logout stuff
  this.loginState.subject.next(false);
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but i think ngrx would be better for sharing data across application.

Comment: That's pretty neat, looks handy for larger applications, it might be hitting a nail with a sledgehammer for smaller ones though. Plus, I'm not sure adding a big dependency is great when Angular can do this natively. I guess there's tradeoffs: https://www.tsmean.com/articles/angular/ngrxstore-vs-angular-services/

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!! It's good

Answer (score 0):

you have a couple of options, you can work with [Input()](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs) and [Output()](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs)  or you could work with a shared service.

for example:
in login.service.ts

```js
isConnected = false;
```

in login.component.ts

```js
public login(){
  this.loginService.isConnected = true;
}
```

in app.component.html

```html
<app-header *ngIf="loginService.isConnected></app-header>
```